# Javascript element selection and modification

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I am creating MCQ options where each option is essentially a div with the class "qinp" inside of which there is a radio button. What I want to do is when the div is clicked, I want the radio button to get checked. There is an input of type radio inside every div with class "qinp". My HTML is something like this-

```html
<div class="qinp">                
    <label class="label-option" for="q1o1">Option 1
         <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1o1">
         <span class="rd-btn">A</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I am using Javascript and I am doing the following-

```js
var number_of_qinps = document.querySelectorAll(".qinp").length;

for(var i = 0; i < number_of_qinps; ++i){
    document.querySelectorAll(".qinp")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){  
          document.querySelectorAll(".qinp")[i].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked = true;
    })
}
```

But for some reason I am getting the following error-

testpage.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined
at HTMLDivElement.

Can someone please explain what is going wrong here? This should have been fairly simple.

Comment: Here's your event listener code, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/z5f1asg2/

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](/q/750486/4642212). `document.querySelectorAll(".qinp")[i]` doesn’t exist at the time you click.

Comment: In general, use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: Why use JS for this in the first place? If you want the div to have the functionality of the label, then why is it itself not the label already?

Comment: Why add javascript, Your input is already being checked, When clicked on div or label.

Comment: You do not need javascript get checked when click div, "for" and "name" HTML element would do the job

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is with var keyword. Replace it with let and that will solve your problem. This is a clouser problem.

```
let number_of_qinps = document.querySelectorAll(".qinp").length;

for(let i = 0; i < number_of_qinps; ++i){
    document.querySelectorAll(".qinp")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){  
          document.querySelectorAll(".qinp")[i].firstElementChild.firstElementChild.checked = true;
    })
}
```